# slf4j/logback - disable console logging

Tags: android, log4j, logback

I want to log to a file ONLY and disable the console logging but this is not working. I think following should work, but it does not. Does anyone know where I make my mistake?

I'm trying to remove any default logger with `detachAndStopAllAppenders` but still, it does not stop logging to the console...

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender;
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy;

public class FileLogger
{
    static Logger mLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileLogger.class);

    public FileLogger(FileLoggingSetup setup)
    {
        if (setup == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("You can't create a FileLogger without providing a setup!");

        init(setup);
    }

    private void init(FileLoggingSetup setup)
    {
        LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        lc.reset();

        // 1) FileLoggingSetup - Encoder for File
        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder1 = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder1.setContext(lc);
        encoder1.setPattern(setup.mLogPattern);
        encoder1.start();

        // 2) FileLoggingSetup - rolling file appender
        RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        rollingFileAppender.setAppend(true);
        rollingFileAppender.setContext(lc);
        //rollingFileAppender.setFile(setup.mFolder + "/" + setup.mFileName + "." + setup.mFileExtension);

        // 3) FileLoggingSetup - Rolling policy (one log per day)
        TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> rollingPolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent>();
        rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(setup.mFolder + "/" + setup.mFileName + "_%d{yyyyMMdd}." + setup.mFileExtension);
        rollingPolicy.setMaxHistory(setup.mDaysToKeep);
        rollingPolicy.setCleanHistoryOnStart(true);
        rollingPolicy.setParent(rollingFileAppender);
        rollingPolicy.setContext(lc);
        rollingPolicy.start();

        rollingFileAppender.setTriggeringPolicy(rollingPolicy);
        rollingFileAppender.setEncoder(encoder1);
        rollingFileAppender.start();

        // add the newly created appenders to the root logger;
        // qualify Logger to disambiguate from org.slf4j.Logger
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) mLogger;
        root.detachAndStopAllAppenders();
        root.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
    }
}
```

**gradle dependencies**

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
compile ('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
}
```

I'm logging via `mLogger.debug(logMessage);` and similar afterwards...

Comment: Please update your question to show your gradle dependencies for `slf4j` and `logback-android`.

Comment: done. Added my imports and my gradle dependencies

Comment: `logback-android` has no loggers by default, so something in your app (or environment) is enabling the console appender. Do you have a `logback.xml` present in `assets/`? Are one of your dependencies using `logback-android`?

Comment: I just opened the .apk and checked the asset folder in there, no xml in there, only some custom fonts... I think, this means, no dependency is using `logback-android`... I personally am not using any xml setups

Comment: The `assets/` being empty does not necessarily mean your deps aren't using `logback-android`. They might also be configuring it imperatively like you are. If you comment out your config code, do you still see console logs? Also what exactly do you see in the logs?

Comment: You were right, some other library (one of my own...) is using the `logback-android` as well. I'm currently mixing two logging libraries of myself because I'm rewritting and open sourcing my new one and am extending it therefore and have not finished updating my code to use the new one only yet... Did not think about that, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, that I was registering another logger in another library and `log4j` is globally set up and so my little log class was logging to the one logger that was registered somewhere else well...